# Lazy load angular directive dependencies

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a page header directive that I would like to include in all of my pages. However within the header I would like to have a login button that is in itself a separate directive. First I would like to designate to the header whether or not it should include the login box on a per page basis. If that option is set to true then I would like to load that specific directive.

Say I define my header like this

```
var header = angular('header',['sessionBox']);

header.directive({....});
```

and my log in directive is defined like this

```
var session = angular.module('sessionBox',[]);

session.directive('logIn',function(){..});
```

Now how would I go about including 'sessionBox' within the header directive?

I thought of using the ng-include directive to load the log-in and compile it, but that will be an issue since the 'sessionBox' is a dependency of the 'header'.

Comment: Use the `ng-if` directive in the template of the header directive to conditionally load the login box.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to load the 'sessionBox' module at the start since it is a dependency of your main module. However I don't see why you couldn't put the code with `session.directive('logIn',function(){..});` into a separate file and load that via ng-include.

I'm not sure why you would want to do this though, I guess it's possible to have so much angular code that you don't want to load it all at the start because the file size is too big, but you would need to have A LOT of code...

Comment: I went your route with ng-include I see that the script does load but the login box does not appear. I have something like this `<div ng-if="loginEnabled"> <ng-include src=" '/sessionBox.js ' "></ng-include> <session-box></session-box> </div>`

Comment: what I meant is that you could ng-include a 'sessionBox.html' file which contains: <script src="/sessionBox.js"></script><session-box></session-box>